# Из базы данных сразу в Input формы

Tags: php, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Здесь,выводятся данные из БД, каждому элементу создается надпись "значение" с его значением.
пример:

- Значение: 14123
- Значение: 3443445
- Значение: абырвалг

Мне необходимо чтобы к каждому элементу создавалась ссылка,или кнопка-для перехода на `page.php` с данными этого элемента методом `POST`

(Грубо: Хочу для каждого элемента индивидуальную страницу)

Возможно ли создание формы, или что то типа `input` к каждому элементу?
Получится ли сделать это "голыми руками" без `JS` и "прочего"?

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM Tablica WHERE znachenie = '12345'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_select);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    do
    {
        printf("<p>Значение:</p> " .$row['name'] );
    } 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    ?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="forma">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="Сюда хочу значение $row[name] "
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo $row[name]; ?>"` так?

Comment: Подобным,добился что выводит в INPUT ВСЕ значения из БД.